# How to change the table value of html in nodejs via socket io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I implemented socket io communication between node js and html

When I run nodejs, java
`socket.emit ('last0', dRealValue);`
dRealValue will be passed to html via a function called'last0'

in html

```
socket.on('last0',function(dRealValue){
            ???;
         });
```

I want the dRealValue to appear in the element named 'real1ch1' (td)

td is one cell of the table

How to write code '???'

form name = ch1setting, table name = ch1table , td name = real1ch1

Answer (score 0):

you will be using javascript in html. jquery is a library that allows you to access html nodes, e.g. a table cell. but you will have to identify that cell by some means. easiest way is by setting a class or id.

```
<td id="changeme"></td>
```

javascript (with jquery):

```
$("#changeme").html("mydata")
```

or without jquery:

```
document.getElementById("changeme").innerHTML = "mydata"
```

if you want to to more complex stuff, use jquery. It will make your life easier.